# Get the height of collision shape for c# (not gdscript)

Tags: c#, godot

On gdscript, it is very easy obtain height:

```
CollisionShape.shape.height
```

But I don't have any idea how to get the height of collision shape on C#. On C# it is missing the reference "Height"

```
CollisionShape.Shape.??
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDScript:

```
$CollisionShape
```

Is equivalent to

```
get_node("CollisionShape")
```

Which translates to C# as:

```
GetNode("CollisionShape")
```

---

However, C# cares for types, so do this:

```
GetNode<CollisionShape>("CollisionShape")
```

Now it should show you the Shape property:

```
GetNode<CollisionShape>("CollisionShape").Shape
```

Ern... Not all `Shape` have "height". C# won't let you use it, until it knows it is a type that has it. I'll assume it is a capsule shape, so do this:

```
var shape = (CapsuleShape)GetNode<CollisionShape>("CollisionShape").Shape;
```

If you are not sure it is a `CapsuleShape`, you can do something like this:

```
if (GetNode<CollisionShape>("CollisionShape").Shape is CapsuleShape shape)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or like this (which could give you null, if it isn't):

```
Shape? shape = GetNode<CollisionShape>("CollisionShape").Shape as CapsuleShape;
```

Now you should be able to get `Height`:

```
var height = shape.Height;
```

*No, the extra variables not always necessary.*

---

If you don't want to use types, you have an alternative -less safe, less performant- way of doing things:

```
var height = (float)GetNode("CollisionShape").Get("Shape").Get("Height");
```

*Sometimes it is convenient to write things like this to begin with, and convert to the other way as necessary. In particular while translating code from GDScript to C#.*

---

It is also possible to do a mix of the two approaches:

```
var height = (float)GetNode<CollisionShape>("CollisionShape").Shape.Get("Height");
```

---

I believe this can also be done in C# using `dynamic`, here:

```
var height = ((dynamic)GetNode("CollisionShape").Shape).Height;
```

Or here:

```
var height = ((dynamic)GetNode("CollisionShape")).Shape.Height;
```

However, you are not going to get IntelliSense.

Comment: Why C # does not allow put on reference in a direct way, aff .. thank you +1

Comment: @Rubénramirez In short, C# won't let you use something that is not part of the type. `Shape` does not have `Height`, instead some of the derived types have it. If it were a type that does not have `Height` and you managed to run code that tries to access it, you would have an error. To be safe, while C# does not know the type, and that the type has `Height`, you can't use it. Well, I suppose it is possible, I added another, using `dynamic`. That should let you use it, but you won't have IntelliSense. You can think of it as "I know better, now let me".